# QT Dialog has incorrect styling

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've been trying various methods of creating a new dialog that needs to be spawned from the main application.

I created a designer form, nothing special about it, and placed some stock widgets on it. Once I finally got it to launch from the main application properly, I noticed that the widgets have no styling to them. The buttons have no border or embossing, all text is white, and the background color of the buttons and LineEdit object are gray. The code used to launch the dialog is as follows:

```cpp
    UpdateDialog dialog(NULL);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.exec();
```

I figured maybe it was being inherited from the parent widget, so I passed NULL as the parent in the constructor for the dialog object and it still happened.

I found one answer to a similar question online suggesting that you can override inherited stylesheets from the parent by setting a stylesheet for the dialog that basically just looks like:

```css
    #objectName {}
```

But this has no effect.

Styles applied to the widget after creation seem to work, as if I use the following line, the text color on the buttons becomes black:

```cpp
    dialog->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0)");
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior? If it matters, we're using Qt 5.6.1 on Scientific Linux (RHEL 6).

**EDIT:** Here is a picture of the dialog.

[image: Dialog without Styling]

There is supposed to be a LineEdit below the label, as well as a button to the right of it, and then two more buttons beneath the LineEdit. Unfortunately the picture quality doesn't let you see it, but there IS a very faint white text where the buttons are supposed to be, so they ARE there, they're just not styled.

**EDIT:** This styling also seems to get applied to the file dialog I spawn from the update dialog seen above.

Comment: Just a random guess: Did you try: `QApplication::setStyle( "WindowsVista" );` or `QApplication::setStyle( "Fusion" );`

Comment: [setupUi](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setupUi)?

Comment: @ChrisMM I should specify that this is a Linux application. But no, there are no application-wide style sheets.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, setupUi is called.

Comment: @ChrisMM I added a picture if it helps you to get an idea of the problem I'm encountering.

Comment: Looking at your picture, it seems the KDE Plasma Oxygen style. Can you confirm? you can use this command to configure it: `kcmshell5 style`. By the way, there is a KDE Plasma program to take screenshots called `spectacle`, which you can use as an alternative to your digital camera :)

Comment: @Pedro I don't know what the style is, as there is no line in our code that explicitly sets it, but if that is the default for SL6.4, then yes. The picture from my camera was because I have to post from my phone and don't have an easy way to transfer screenshots from this machine to my phone.

Comment: If you execute the command `kcmshell5 style` what do you see?

Comment: If you can't post your question from the development computer, then maybe you can't execute arbitrary commands, or install packages, or adjust any configuration. Is that true?

Comment: @Pedro No, I have full control over that. As I said, I CAN take them, but it was faster and easier this way. Also, executing that command does nothing, as that command is not present on the machine in question.

Comment: Sorry, that command was for KDE Plasma 5, but SL6 has only KDE4. Please see my answer for the correct command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt [does not have](https://www.qt.io/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion) a strong visual identity of its own. Instead, it tries to provide a native look and feel on all its target platforms. All operating systems include some look-and-feel customization capabilities, but in this area Linux is special, because there is not a single, unique user interface like in Windows and macOS, but there are several. Two well known desktops for Linux (and other Unix-like Operating Systems) are Gnome and KDE. Some distributions install Gnome as default, and a few install the other. Most allow to install both, and the user can choose one at the login screen, or in a desktop configuration setting.

I've never tried Scientific Linux before, but I know Fedora so it wasn't a big deal to install SL6 in a VirtualBox VM to see if I could reproduce your issue (I couldn't!). What I've noticed is that SL6 defaults to Gnome desktop (like RH and Fedora, btw). It does not include Qt5 and it would be difficult to install a Qt5 development environment on it, because it ships an outdated GCC compiler. It is possible to deploy Qt 5.6 applications and libraries on it, though. I've installed KDE in the VM as well with this command:

```
    sudo yum -y groupinstall "KDE Desktop"
```

SL6 does not include KDE Plasma, of course, because it requires Qt5. It is KDE4.3 instead, based on Qt4.6. So, in this version, correcting my previous comment, the configuration command for changing/inspecting KDE styles is:

```
    kcmshell4 style
```

The default style for KDE4 is Oxygen, as I've deduced by your picture. The color scheme for KDE programs can be configured with this command:

```
    kcmshell4 colors
```

To try your scenario, I've made a simple Qt5 Widgets program, which I could deploy on the VM along with the dependent Qt5 libraries. I've used [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) to deploy the library and plugins required by the program and create a self contained directory for easy transfer and installing. Anyway, I want to show you how the program looks on my development Linux machine, with my preferred dark-breeze theme:

[image: dark-breeze theme]

After deploying the program directory to the SL6 VM, running it under the default Gnome desktop, it looks like this:

[image: gtk+ theme in Gnome]

And this is the look when running the program under KDE:

[image: fusion theme in KDE]

Remember that we are looking at the same build of the same program, just changing the running environment. Just for your information, I've instrumented my program a little, including in the `main()` function this debugging statement:

```
     qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys();
```

Which prints this output on Linux:

> ("Windows", "GTK+", "Fusion")

And also included this debug statement at the main window constructor:

```
    qDebug() << this->style();
```

The output of that statement depends on the desktop environment. Under Gnome (which is based on the gtk+ toolkit) it outputs something like this:

> QGtkStyle(0x11b39f0, name = "gtk+")

While under the KDE desktop it outputs:

> QFusionStyle(0x1428990, name = "fusion")

I hope that at this point you can deduce like me that the origin of your problem must be the color configuration under KDE in your SL6. To prove that theory, please run some other Qt programs and see if they show the same inappropriate colors. In that case, my advice is to fix that configuration (by running `kcmshell4 colors`) instead of changing the program to force some fixed color scheme, because a good desktop integration is a valued asset for most Linux users.

Anyway, if you want to create a fixed color scheme hardcoded in your program, I give you this example that you can include in your main.cpp to be applied to the whole program.

```
static QPalette qt_fusionPalette()
{
    QColor backGround(239, 239, 239);
    QColor light = backGround.lighter(150);
    QColor mid(backGround.darker(130));
    QColor midLight = mid.lighter(110);
    QColor base = Qt::white;
    QColor disabledBase(backGround);
    QColor dark = backGround.darker(150);
    QColor darkDisabled = QColor(209, 209, 209).darker(110);
    QColor text = Qt::black;
    QColor hightlightedText = Qt::white;
    QColor disabledText = QColor(190, 190, 190);
    QColor button = backGround;
    QColor shadow = dark.darker(135);
    QColor disabledShadow = shadow.lighter(150);

    QPalette fusionPalette(Qt::black,backGround,light,dark,mid,text,base);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Midlight, midLight);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Button, button);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Shadow, shadow);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::HighlightedText, hightlightedText);

    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Text, disabledText);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::WindowText, disabledText);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::ButtonText, disabledText);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Base, disabledBase);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Dark, darkDisabled);
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Shadow, disabledShadow);

    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Highlight, QColor(48, 140, 198));
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Highlight, QColor(48, 140, 198));
    fusionPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Highlight, QColor(145, 145, 145));
    return fusionPalette;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setPalette(qt_fusionPalette());
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This light color palette is the same as the standard Qt's "Fusion" [palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html). If you prefer a dark color scheme, you may find one [here](https://gist.github.com/QuantumCD/6245215).

Comment: There are several Qt applications running on this system, none of which have exhibited this behavior. It appears ONLY in the dialog I have created and the file picker dialog spawned from one of the buttons in the dialog. No issues have appeared in the parent application that spawns this dialog, nor any of the other child dialogs spawned by this application.

Comment: In that case, the QPalette for the dialogs have been modified, either by your code or by something else. As I've said, I couldn't reproduce your issue, so I can't provide any other advice, unless you can create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: An useful diagnostic would be if you log-in with Gnome and run your program under that desktop environment.

Comment: So after looking into the rest of the application, it seems there is an application-wide palette. I was not aware of palettes before you brought them to my attention, as I'm still very new to the UI portion of Qt. I tried setting the standard palette on the widget to overwrite the application-wide one and it did change things, but still looked off. I'm going to try the static palette you defined above,  but as far as I'm concerned, this has been solved.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Remember that unless you set a specific QStyle or a specific stylesheet, your widget will be decorated with the OS provided style. So since you did not show your code, no one could have told you what's wrong in your code. Next time, don't forget to include a minimal, complete and reproducible example ;)

Comment: @Fareanor Yeah, I just wasn't aware that the style could also be called a palette in Qt. When I was initially searching for the cause,  I was searching for the keywords "setStyle" and "setStyleSheet" in the application, not "setPalette". So I thought there was something wrong with how I created the dialog.

Comment: @Pedro The coloring is correct now. The only thing that still isn't right is that the buttons have no border or embossing. They just look like labels.

Comment: I am glad that you finally solved the issue, but... *the style could also be called a palette in Qt*?. That is not true. `QPalette` and `QStyle` are two different and complementary classes. `QStyle` provides and uses a [standardPalette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#standardPalette). In your case:  `QStyle` draws the buttons using the colors provided by a `QPalette`. By the way, `QPushButton` has a [flat property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#flat-prop) that also influences its look (making it to look 'flat').